# Square SDK can't pair Reader through bluetooth

Tags: android, react-native, square-connect, square

I have an application which integrated Square Reader SDK (v.1.2.2) to take payment, when I approach to Setting to pair Reader. After seconds, the SDK show "Failed to Pair". Then I check the device connect info. The app and Reader connect through Headset Jack instead of Bluetooth.

[image]

I've tried many times follow the guide in popup. But can't connect too.

[image]

[image]

Document: https://github.com/square/react-native-square-reader-sdk/blob/master/docs/get-started.md

Comment: Based on the second screenshot it sounds like your device is rooted which isn't supported. Are all three screenshots the same device, or different devices?

Comment: On that device, the Square Point Of Sale (Square) can play as well.

Comment: I've unroot that device already, but that screen still show

Comment: So just to confirm, you can connect the reader in POS but not ReaderSDK? Would you be able to do a factory restore to confirm all root traces are removed and try again?

Comment: I confirm the Square app can connect Reader and make payment as well. But the SDK in our app can't pair Reader. For Square App, the port connect with Reader through Bluetooth. But in SDK, it connects through Headset Jack. That's different thing between Square and SDK which found.

Comment: I'm not following. Both the ReaderSDK and Square App can connect to the bluetooth reader (you do not need a headset jack). Are you trying with headset jack or bluetooth?

Comment: The Reader SDK do connect and pick Headset Jack automatically. Noway to change, that's automatic.